# CiviCRM Dashboard Not Working - WordPress installation

Tags: dashboard

I had no errors when installing CiviCRM (with Sample Data checked); I just had to manually create the database. The only "warning" was that my hosting company is using PHP 5.4.

I can see the CiviCRM link on the dashboard menu, but nothing drops down. On the right (CiviCRM Home) I only see the welcome message and some links. When I click the "System Status: Error" link, the welcome message blurb disappears, but no error message or anything else appears. Refreshing the dashboard data on CiviCRM Home does not help.

CiviCRM 4.7.7

WordPress 4.5.2 - fresh install on a subdirectory of my main site

No other plugins activated.

wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php - settings file is here

PHP 5.4.45

wp-content/plugins/files - full permissions (777)

BASEURL - http://paintballheroes.ablewebs.com

I am trying to test CiviCRM before we make the decision to use it for our not-for-profit organization (BC Balance and Dizziness Disorders Society http://www.balanceanddizziness.org). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **civicrm log** in /../uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog or /../plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

Check the **error_log**. phpinfo() will tell you where it is.

I had upgrade problems because the CONSTRAINT clauses were missing for my FOREIGN KEYS